# How to remove time-field string from a date-as-character variable?

Tags: string, r, substring, date-formatting

Suppose I have a variable like this

```
c<-c("9/21/2011 0:00:00",  "9/25/2011 0:00:00",  "10/2/2011 0:00:00",  
"9/28/2011 0:00:00",  "9/27/2011 0:00:00")
```

what's a quick way to remove all `0:00:00`s so that

```
c
[1] "9/21/2011" "9/25/2011" "10/2/2011" "9/28/2011" "9/27/2011"
```

Comment: Use the `gsub` function. There must be many, many worked examples in SO archives.

Comment: May you give an answer here using the example? +1

Comment: This may work `sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s+"), "[", 1)` but you may want to actually work with this data as a date (`as.Date`).

Comment: I think the question isn't asking for full generality, only *How to remove time-field string from a date-as-character variable?*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can turn them into dates and then format as desired, e.g.:

```
v <- c("9/21/2011 0:00:00",  "9/25/2011 0:00:00",  "10/2/2011 0:00:00",  
     "9/28/2011 0:00:00",  "9/27/2011 0:00:00")
v <- format(as.POSIXct(v,format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'),format='%m/%d/%Y')
> v
[1] "09/21/2011" "09/25/2011" "10/02/2011" "09/28/2011" "09/27/2011"
```

Or, you can simply remove the `" 0:00:00"` substring using gsub:

```
v <- gsub(x=v,pattern=" 0:00:00",replacement="",fixed=T)
> v
[1] "9/21/2011" "9/25/2011" "10/2/2011" "9/28/2011" "9/27/2011"
```

Comment: a simpler way could be to use [Round](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/round.POSIXt.html) with `unit="day"` on date types

Comment: use [round_date](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/round_date.html) for date-time objects in `lubridate`

Comment: @cengel: well, the example of the OP wasn't talking about dates, but strings containing dates, so I'd prefer to avoid loading an external package just to remove some suffix from a string...

Comment: A great tip to remove the date part from date-time. I just modified the code like this: `v <- format(as.POSIXct(v,format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'),format='%H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 13):

From the lubridate package: Use `mdy_hms()` to read in the characters as Month, Day, Year and Hours, Minutes, Seconds, then wrap with `as.Date()` to strip the time.

```
library(lubridate)
v <- c("9/21/2011 0:00:00",  "9/25/2011 0:00:00",  "10/2/2011 0:00:00",  
       "9/28/2011 0:00:00",  "9/27/2011 0:00:00")
v <- as.Date(mdy_hms(v))
v
# [1] "2011-09-21" "2011-09-25" "2011-10-02" "2011-09-28" "2011-09-27"
```

If you want to maintain the vector as character type, not date type:

```
v <- as.character(as.Date(mdy_hms(v)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Keeping original class as character. Use gsub (or sub) to remove everything after space. The `.*` pattern will find the first space.

```
c<-c("9/21/2011 0:00:00",  "9/25/2011 0:00:00",  "10/2/2011 0:00:00",  
     "9/28/2011 0:00:00",  "9/27/2011 0:00:00")

gsub(" .*","", c)
[1] "9/21/2011" "9/25/2011" "10/2/2011" "9/28/2011" "9/27/2011"
```