# How keep only date variable without time-field string

Tags: r

My question takes a general aspect comparing to which was proposed here [How to remove time-field string from a date-as-character variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089895/how-to-remove-time-field-string-from-a-date-as-character-variable).

In fact, suppose I have this date type variable:

```
> head(DataDia$Date)
[1] "2016-09-13 15:56:30.827" "2016-12-12 13:39:17.537" "2016-09-16 21:57:24.977" "2016-09-23 11:19:22.010"
[5] "2017-01-11 20:06:58.490" "2016-10-21 23:40:43.927"
```

How do I delete all time-field strings and just keep the date format. SO that I get this:

```
> head(DataDia$Date)
[1] "2016-09-13" "2016-12-12" "2016-09-16" "2016-09-23"
[5] "2017-01-11" "2016-10-21"
```

Note please that I am working on a data table. So I need a way using data.table 
operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `as.Date(DataDia$Date)`.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use:

`as.POSIXct(Df$Date,format='%Y-%m-%d',tz= "UTC")`

Answer (score 0):

Combining `as.Date` and `as.character`

```
x = c("2016-09-13 15:56:30.827", "2016-12-12 13:39:17.537", "2016-09-16 21:57:24.977", "2016-09-23 11:19:22.010",
        "2017-01-11 20:06:58.490", "2016-10-21 23:40:43.927")

y = as.character(as.Date(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

y
[1] "2016-09-13" "2016-12-12" "2016-09-16" "2016-09-23" "2017-01-11" "2016-10-21"
```

Comment: Why do you load lubridate?

Comment: That's true. It could work as a base solution. Thanks

Comment: What's the point of `as.character`?